# Queue is empty even though there are items in it

Tags: django, multithreading, python-2.7, queue, gunicorn

I have a django app in which I'm using Queue.

```
class DataThread (threading.Thread):
    data_queue = Queue.Queue()
```

In another thread I have stuff being added to the queue like below

```
DataThread.data_queue.put(msg)
```

And it is being consumed in **DataThread** in the below fashion

```
while True:
    self.sendMessagesFromQueue()
    time.sleep(1)
def sendMessagesFromQueue(self):
    try:
        while not DataThread.data_queue.empty():
            data = self.data_queue.get()
            #Some processing logic
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
```

Now this works when I run it using `python manage.py runserver`  (using django itself).
But it doesn't work when I use **gunicorn** to run this app. Because the queue empty check keeps returning its empty but when i check queue size at the location I add to the queue, it keeps building up.

EDIT: I even checked if the queues are the same. They have the same memory locations. Also I'm not sure if this helps, but these threads are created before gunicorn starts. I'm making this in a sitecustomize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that gunicorn forks and creates multiple worker processes unlike Django's webserver that only creates threads. Since all of the above question is done before gunicorn forks, the gunicorn fork's copy over the address space but not the threads. Therefore, the Queues will exist at the same virtual address and will be there in each process created by gunicorn and data will be put into each queue in those newly created worker processes. But, the consuming or the Queue.get() happens only in the initial process where there is no Queue.put taking place.

I fixed it by using [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) instead. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

Create a queue and insert 5 integers to it. Then write a method EvenNumber that 
prints the even data stored in the queue. Test your method in the main class.

Comment: How does this answer the original question?

Comment: Why did I just get a rep loss? The notification points to this answer.. did @Jojo A just downvote my question/answer coz he is getting downvotes for his irrelevant answer?